# trouble using AsyncTasks in my tabbed app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, tabs

I have created a tabbed app. In one of the tabs I have code that reads and displays messages that comes in through the usb port. It works fine when I click on the tab, but my problem arises when I move to a different tab and come back. Through debugging I have learned that a new AsyncTasks task is created and the `onPreExecute()` runs both times, but `doInBackground()` only runs the first time.

It doesn't really make sense why `onPreExecute()` would run when I leave the tab and come back but `doInBackground()` doesn't run.

below is my `onResume()` and `onPause()` for the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("DEBUG", "onResume Runs");
    display = new displayMessages();    //displayMessages() is the name of the AsyncTask
    display.execute();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MainActivity.setTabBoolean(3, false);
    display.cancel(true);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Receiver task Canceled. is cancelled = " + String.valueOf(display.isCancelled()));
}
```

Comment: When scrolling through tabs are you sure that onPause() is actually called between tabs? Possibly the asynctask continues doinbackground whilst you navigate away?

Comment: `onPause()` does run and I know that because  `display.isCancelled()` evaluates to true.